# How to flip two views when their incorrect automatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm looking to create a Memory game, and I'm working on the functionality right now. I have gotten the general sense of the logic to the project down, but I want to add in a little detail. One of the details I want to add is having the two selected cards when they are incorrect, to turn by themselves after 1 second. i tried using Handler().postDelay but it didn't seem to work.

Here is the code

```
class GamePlay1Fragment : Fragment() {

//    lateinit var front_anim: AnimatorSet
//    lateinit var back_anim: AnimatorSet

    private lateinit var pieces: List<ImageView>
    private lateinit var gameCards: List<GameCard>
    private var indexOfSelectedPiece: Int? = null


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: Gameplay1FragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.gameplay1_fragment,
            container, false)


        binding.backButtonView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
            v.findNavController().navigate(GamePlay1FragmentDirections.actionGamePlay1FragmentToLobbyFragment())
        }


        val images = mutableListOf(memorybatcardfront, memorycatcardfront, memorycowcardfront,
            memorydragonfront, memorygarbagemancardfront, memoryghostdogcardfront)

        images.addAll(images)

        images.shuffle()

        pieces = listOf(binding.card1back, binding.card2back, binding.card3back, binding.card4back, binding.card5back,binding.card6back, binding.card7back,
                        binding.card8back, binding.card9back, binding.card10back, binding.card11back, binding.card12back)

        gameCards = pieces.indices.map { index ->
            GameCard(images[index])
        }


            pieces.forEachIndexed { index, piece ->
                piece.setOnClickListener {

                    updatingModels(index)

                    updatingViews()
                }
            }



        return binding.root
    }

    private fun updatingViews() {
        gameCards.forEachIndexed { index, gameCard ->
          val piece = pieces[index]
            piece.setImageResource(if (gameCard.isFacedUp) gameCard.id else allcardbacks)
        }
    }

    private fun updatingModels(position: Int) {
        val gameCard = gameCards[position]

        if (gameCard.isFacedUp) return


        if (indexOfSelectedPiece == null) {
            restoreGameCards()
            indexOfSelectedPiece = position

        }
        else {
            checkingForMatch(indexOfSelectedPiece!!, position)
            indexOfSelectedPiece = null
        }
        gameCard.isFacedUp = !gameCard.isFacedUp
    }

    private fun restoreGameCards() {
        val handler = Handler()
        for (gameCard in gameCards) {
            if (!gameCard.isMatched) {
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
                gameCard.isFacedUp = false

            }

        }
    }

    private fun checkingForMatch(position1: Int, position2: Int) {
        if (gameCards[position1].id == gameCards[position2].id) {
          gameCards[position1].isMatched = true
            gameCards[position2].isMatched = true
        }
    }

    private val runnable = Runnable(){
        kotlin.run {
        }
    }

}
```

If there is another way to do it, I'm all ears. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you filp the card synchronously with invoking the handler (i.e. they execute at the same time), but instead you need to flip the card whenever the handler delay is over.

To fix this you need to transfer the card flipping within the `Runnable` of the `Handler`:

```
private fun restoreGameCards() {
    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    for (gameCard in gameCards) {
        if (!gameCard.isMatched) {
            handler.postDelayed({
                gameCard.isFacedUp = false // Executes after 1000 millisec
            }, 1000)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It did work, but not how it I intended it to work. The delay does happen, but now you can click multiple cards before all the cards that were clicked turn face down.

Comment: So, you need to bind the delay after the user clicks multiple cards.. and when the user finishes; you need to flip these cards I guess?

Comment: Right. After the second card is flipped, if there's not a match then there is a 1 sec delay before both cards flip back over.